# __attritbute__((aligned(8))) on structure tag as well as structure member

Tags: c, gcc

I have tried below program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct __attribute__((packed,aligned(8))) Ball {

    int  size;
    int s1;
    int s2 __attribute__((packed,aligned(16)));
    double q __attribute__((packed,aligned(16)));
} Ball_t;

Ball_t var;
int main()
{
   printf("%lu\n",sizeof(Ball_t));
   printf("%p %p %p %p\n",&var.size,&var.s1,&var.s2,&var.q);
   return 0;
}

Output-
48
0x601060 0x601064 0x601070 0x601080
```

I have expected the output like- sizeof structure should be 40 bytes.
But, I am getting 48 bytes. As per my understanding, alignment  should happen  like this-

```
(let suppose start address of structure is 0)

typedef struct __attribute__((packed,aligned(8))) Ball {
    int  size;  // start at 0th and occupy 4 bytes
    int s1;      //start at 4th and occupy 4 bytes  + padding of 8 bytes
    int s2 __attribute__((packed,aligned(16)));  // starts at 16th byte and occupy 4 bytes +padding 12 bytes
    double q __attribute__((packed,aligned(16))); //starts at 32nd and occupy 8 bytes 
} Ball_t;
```

So,total size will be 4+4+ 8+4 +12+8=40. Please clarify me if I am wrong in understanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't it be `8 + 8 + 16 + 16` ? You require `aligned(8)` on each member and `aligned(16)` on the final two members. Looks like 48, but note it is not guaranteed the same on all compilers or operating systems.

Comment: I think, I am not clear with __attribute__((aligned(8)) if it is applied to structure. what i understood that structure will start at multiple of 8 ie 0,8,16,24,32.... This alignment will not be applicable to member of structure. means if would be applicable  to each member of structure  , then the address of s1 should be 0x601068 rather than 0x601064. Please correct me if I am wrong. And compiler and os where i have run this program is gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Comment: First I don't think packed can be used with aligned. But that seems to work. Your confusion is caused the alignment of the struct as a whole. Say you have an array of `Ball_t`, then you will find all `s2` members and all `q` members are all aligned to 16 bytes. To achieve that, s2 members of neighboring elements must be at least 48 bytes apart. Finally, you will find in C standard that `sizeof` is defined as "average storage used by a element in an array with padding included if any".

Comment: Simply, if `sizeof(Ball_t)==40`, then the even elements in an array would be perfectly aligned, but odd elements would not have their `s2` and `q` members aligned to a 16-byte boundary.

Comment: Checking with `offsetof` (in `stddef.h`) shows the offsets of the members to be `size : 0, s1 : 4, s2 : 16, q : 32` (which itself requires `16-byte` alignment resulting in `sizeof` returning `48`) Try it yourself by adding `printf ("\n size : %zu\n s1   : %zu\n s2   : %zu\n q    : %zu\n", offsetof (Ball_t, size), offsetof (Ball_t, s1), offsetof (Ball_t, s2), offsetof (Ball_t, q));` to your code. In other words `s1` requires `12-bytes` to make `s2` `16-byte` aligned.

Comment: I agree what u have explained. I agree , the starting address of q will be 32 if structure starting address is 0 but, why q requires 16 bytes, it is a double that takes 8 bytes,__attribute__((aligned(16)__ , the starting address of q should be multiple of 8 ie 0,16,32,48.... . Let suppose I have taken the array of structure, like Ball_t a[3]; let suppose a base address is 0, a[0].size ,a[0].s1, a[0].s2, a[0].q will have offset 0,4,16,32. if i m considering the addr of structure is 40, then offset of  a[1].size ,a[1].s1, a[1].s2, a[1].q ll be 40,44,48,64,72. Then why 48 size is required?

Comment: because in if that were the case, even elements and odd elements would have different layouts. 4+4+ (8)+4 +(12)+8 v.s. 4+4+4+(12)+8+(8)